# Android How to save the value of editText even when the app is terminated

Tags: android, android-edittext

I made this app which the user inputs the school name, and it will link to the website.
So, I want to know how to save the school name, so you don't have to put it in every time you open the app. Thank you.

My app contains an edittext, a go button (Which I want to use it as a save also), and a webview.

Comment: use shared preferences here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: Use storage classes like sqlite or mysql(online storage),Sharedpreference.. my request store sqite or mysql

Comment: Any more solution  please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the value using something like this:

```
final EditText eActNametwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eACTNametwo);
    final EditText eActBudtwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eACTBudtwo);

    bCreatetwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCreateActivitytwo);
    bCreatetwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences settingstwo = getSharedPreferences(actnamefiletwo,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editortwo = settingstwo.edit();
            editortwo.putString("nametwo", eActNametwo.getText().toString());
            editortwo.putString("budtwo", eActBudtwo.getText().toString());
            editortwo.commit();
        }
    });
```

and then u call the value somewhere using this

```
entvActNametwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActNametwo);
    tvActBudtwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActBudtwo);
    SharedPreferences settingstwo = getSharedPreferences(actnamefiletwo, 0);
    tvActNametwo.setText(settingstwo.getString("nametwo", ""));
    tvActBudtwo.setText(settingstwo.getString("budtwo", ""));
```

you will need to call your string prior to onCreate like this:

```
public static final String actnamefiletwo = "actnamebudtwo";
```

This is an example from my own app, hope it helps

Comment: But it's kind of confusing. Can you show me your full code? I can't really tell where to put them between web client.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you looking at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html 
For this particular point where's there is only one string to store, I'd use the SharedPreference 
You'll find what you need on the training guide ;)

Comment: This is nice too. Thanks.